# Javascript function formats number to return NaN

Tags: javascript

This bit of code in a JS file I am using which formats the number to add .00 on the end. Only issue is my number is 0.7321 and it returns NaN.  Any idea how to modify it?

```
  self.formatFloat = function (number) {
            var split = number.toString().split('.');
            var decimal = (split[1] !== undefined? split[1] : '') + (new Array(3-(split[1] !== undefined? split[1].length : 0))).join('0');
            return split[0] + '.' + decimal;
        };
```

Comment: Where'd you find that code?

Comment: *"This bit of code in a JS file I am using which formats the number to add .00 on the end."* [Simpler solution: `num.toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/

Comment: FYI, since the code doesn't apply any mathematical operations on the input or the result, I don't think it's this code which causes the result to be `NaN`. When I pass in `0.344`, I actually get `"0.344"` back. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Consider Math.floor and then multiply by 100.

Comment: @Terry: I think you got the order of operations wrong.

Comment: @slebetman -- Hmm, another senior moment on my part. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Felix-Kling should win this answer

```
self.formatFloat=function (number) {
  return number.toFixed(2);
};
```

Comment: Yes this works great thanks.  Thanks to Felix as well.  Whats the etiquette here of giving the answer then?

Comment: Not sure, but if @felix-kling post his comment as an answer un-accept mine and accept his.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Math.round(num * 100) / 100`